# How to move specific line of file into another using php?

Tags: php

In a file I have array of lines. Some lines would have some error. So I need to move the error lines of string to another file. I don't know how to move a specific line in to another file.
I can delete the line but I need it in a separate file.

```
$str=file_get_contents('file1');
$li = preg_split("/(\r\n|\n|\r)/",$str );
$c=count($li);
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
    if(is_numeric($li[$i])){
        //have to move this line into another file
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `file_put_contents()`, the following would create a new file called `file_{n}.txt` and add the line for each match:

```
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
    if(is_numeric($li[$i])){
        file_put_contents("file_$i.txt", $li[$i]);
    }
}
```